# fatal error: call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in my student_db

Tags: php, mysql

Getting a fatal error on line 22 of my student_db.

```
function get_student_by_id($studentID) {  //Fatal error on line 22 which is (get_student_by_id).
    global $db;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM student_table
          WHERE StudentID = $studentID";
    try {
        $student = $db->query($query);
        $student = $student->fetchall();
        return $student;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $error_message = $e->getMessage();
        include('../errors/database_error.php');
        exit();
    }
}
```

Error message

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in 
C:\wamp\www\CRSProject\model\student_db.php on line 22
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0007  164648  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
2   0.0139  225544  get_student_by_id( )    ..\index.php:51
```

Comment: I don't see any `fetch()` being called.

Comment: well I guessing you are trying to use the function `fetch()` on something that is not an object. So you either did a typo in your object name or your object is == null.

Comment: @user3261231 please consider using PDO or mySQLi function they are more secure and you should also use bind parameters that would help not getting SQL injection (maybe mixe up some `htmlspecialchars()` or something so you dont get HTML injection (but I wouldn't worry so much for html injection since you're reading in the DB not writing))

Comment: Isn't supposed to be $student = `$student->fetchAll();` with a "A"

Comment: @Lorenzo I am not sure but i think PHP is not case sensitive.

Comment: @Machavity do you mean           $Student = $db->prepare($query);
                   $Student-> bindValue(':studentID', $StudentID);
                    $Student->execute();
                    $Students = $Student->fetch();
               $Student->closeCursor();